# How many records are loaded into the BindingSource?

Tags: c#, data-binding, ado.net

I've always worked with Linq and that's why I always brought only the necessary records for operation - obviously everything was hand-coded.

Now, I'm studying Data Binding because I understand that I can speed up the whole process a lot.

However, I have a question about the initial load of the BindingSource. I noticed that the sample codes always contain the .Load () command without specifying an initial filter.

Example:

```
dbContext ctx = new dbContex();
ctx.Table.Load(); <-- Here is my doubt
myBindingSource.DataSource = ctx.Table.Local.ToBindingList()
```

Let's assume that this table has 10,000 records. Will it load 10,000 records at once? Doesn't this type of operation make the load very slow and consume a lot of network bandwidth?

Comment: Very interesting question! I would generate 10 000 dummy records into a dummy table and check this with a debugger.

Comment: Nothing is stopping it (filter) from how many records you want, therefore, I would assume every single one [see more maybe here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/load-method)

Comment: It's the impression I got: full load.

How do I bring only the records that matter? I am not talking about using the BindingSource Filter because it will only filter when viewing the components connected to it. I really want to upload only the records that interest me.

Suppose I have a record of 10,000 pieces and 8,000 are no longer manufactured but I have the record because of history. So, I want to load only the 2,000 that are still available. How would I do that in this method?

Comment: @WillianLopes I would suggest looking into the documents (querying), they are the best and most informant.

Comment: I believe you should be able to pass some parameters to that Load method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation

> One common way to do this is to write a LINQ query and then call ToList on it, only to immediately discard the created list. The Load extension method works just like ToList except that it avoids the creation of the list altogether.

So, if you just call

```
ctx.Table.Load()
```

it will load all the data on that table.

You can also query it before calling Load()

```
context.Posts.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("stackoverflow")).Load();
```